# Объясните, пожалуйста, условие if (S&(1<<j))

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Перебрать все возможные суммы элементов массива.
Поясните, пожалуйста, как в этом случае работают побитовые операции в if.

```
long S;
int a[N];

// Заполните массив a - рандомно или вводом - по вкусу
for (m = 1, i = 0; i < N; i++)
    m = 2*m;  // m - количество точек перебора

for (S = 1; S < m; S++)
{
    for (j = 0, sum = 0; j < N; j++) 
        if (S & (1 << j))
        {
            printf("+%d", a[j]);
            sum += a[j];
        }
    printf ("=%d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Проверяем, установлен ли бит j

Comment: если N >= 32 код работать не будет

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с `1 << j` - это сдвиг 1 влево на `j` позиций.

Операция `&` - побитовое И, которое дает 1 в некоторой позиции результата, если в этой позиции в обоих операндах 1, и 0 в противном случае.

Итак - `S&(1<<j)` дает ненулевое значение (истину :)) тогда и только тогда, когда в `S` бит в `j`-ой позиции равен 1.

Comment: @entithat Насколько я знаю, "забронирован" только один - 0 означает успешное завершение.

Comment: @entithat В лучшем случае где-то в Linux. Ни в каком стандарте **С++** эти коды не оговорены.

Comment: окей. Спасибо. Лабораторная какая-то непонятная.